# Condition variable signalling issue

Tags: c, linux, variables, pthreads, conditional-statements

I am in a soup. The idea may be bad but i do need a solution.

- I have two condition variable, say A and B.
- Threads 1, 2 and 3 are waiting on A. Thread 4 is waiting on B.
- B will be pthread_cond-signal() by thread 2, that is thread 4 will be
  signaled to wake up by thread 2.

Now, I have another thread 5 which pthread_cond_broadcasts() on condition variable A. I need all threads 1, 2 and 3 to wake up before thread 4 wakes up. That is say if thread 2 wakes up and signals on B thread 4 may wake up before thread 3 does, which is not what i want.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [semaphore](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview): have each of threads 1-3 post the semaphore, and have thread 4 wait on the semaphore 3 times instead of on a condition variable.

You'll want to use [`sem_init(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_init) or [`sem_open(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_open) to create the semaphore, [`sem_post(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_post) to post the semaphore, [`sem_wait(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_wait) to wait on the semaphore, and then either [`sem_destroy(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_destroy) (if created with `sem_init`) or [`sem_close(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_close) and [`sem_unlink(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_unlink) (if created with `sem_open`) to destroy the semaphore.

Comment: @Adam...great. Let me try out nd get back

Answer (score 2):

You *can* solve this using condition variables.  Instead of having Thread 4 wait just for the condition set by Thread 2, have it wait for a condition that is only set after *all* of Thread 1, Thread 2 and Thread 3 have done their thing:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&thread4_lock);
while (!thread1_flag || !thread2_flag || !thread3_flag)
    pthread_cond_wait(&thread4_cond, &thread4_lock);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread4_lock);

/* Thread 4 can continue */
```

When Thread 1 has done its thing, it sets its part of the condition:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&thread4_lock);
thread1_flag = 1;
pthread_cond_signal(&thread4_cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread4_lock);
```

...and likewise for Thread 2 and Thread 3.  Thread 4 will only continue once all the flags have been set.

Comment: This will work, but don't forget that `thread11_flag`, `thread2_flag`, and `thread3_flag` should be declared `volatile`, and you also need a proper memory barrier on non-x86 systems to ensure that the memory updates are visible to other processors.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: `volatile` and a barrier are not required, because those three flags are protected by the `thread4_lock` mutex as per the example.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ZeroMQ's in-process signalling for this. ZeroMQ implements a messaging model which can be used effectively to coordinate threads, as well as for inter process or network messaging.

For more info: http://api.zeromq.org/2-1-1:zmq-inproc

Here is an example of load-balancing between threads using ZeroMQ and Java.